# is there Raw RTC output?

Tags: programming, rtc

I have an I2C Real Time Clock, DS3231 RTC module , and I just want something like Unix Time.
I'm using the uRTCLib, looking at the [class methods](https://naguissa.github.io/uRTCLib_doc_and_extras/classuRTCLib.html#af8eea2501d6b82726ce6226529c82a89)
but dont see anything like that. I'm thinking there must be a raw read that would return all the digits. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DS3231 doesn't report the Unix time. It reports the current time in
broken-down form (year, month... second). If you need Unix time, you
have to compute it.

I suggest using Adafruit's [RTClib](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib). This library implements the
computation of Unix time, e.g.

```cpp
uint32_t unix_time = rtc.now().unixtime();
```